# Fedora Tor Failed to bind one of the listener ports

Tags: linux, fedora, tor, selinux

Tor Log:

```
Jun 03 15:12:53.463 [notice] Tor 0.4.7.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1n, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.5.2 and Glibc 2.34 as libc.
Jun 03 15:12:53.463 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
Jun 03 15:12:53.463 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jun 03 15:12:53.464 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 8192 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Jun 03 15:12:53.466 [warn] /run/tor is not owned by this user (toranon, 979) but by <unknown> (777). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Jun 03 15:12:53.466 [warn] Before Tor can create a control socket in "/run/tor/control", the directory "/run/tor" needs to exist, and to be accessible only by the user and group account that is running Tor.  (On some Unix systems, anybody who can list a socket can connect to it, so Tor is being careful.)
Jun 03 15:12:53.466 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:1234
Jun 03 15:12:53.466 [notice] Opened OR listener connection (ready) on 0.0.0.0:1234
Jun 03 15:12:53.466 [notice] Closing partially-constructed OR listener connection (ready) on 0.0.0.0:1234
Jun 03 15:12:53.466 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Jun 03 15:12:53.466 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

It worked once and I am sure that nothing is using that port already. (`sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 1234`)

It might be something with Selinux but there's nothing in the Tor manual that helps me.

Is there a known problem and I don't know of it? It seems unknown to me...